# How to create a NSPredicate to find entries with leading numerical value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm using NSPredicates to fetch entities based on a name attribute. Creating a predicate for names beginning with letters was easy (@"name BEGINSWITH %@", searchLetter), however now I'd like to fetch all entities with a name that begins with a numerical value, or rather a non-alphabetical character.

What would be the appropriate predicate expression here?

Right now I don't want to get too deep into predicate programming, as this is all I need right now and time flies. So, please, don't point me to the Predicate Programming Guide, I just need that expression.. :)

Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `MATCHES` operator doesn't work with a fetch request, then you'll essentially have to do stuff manually:

```
NOT(name BEGINSWITH[cd] 'a' OR name BEGINSWITH[cd] 'b' OR ... OR name BEGINSWITH[cd] 'z')
```

That would get everything that does not start with a letter.  Likewise:

```
name BEGINSWITH[cd] '0' OR name BEGINSWITH[cd] '1' OR ... OR name BEGINSWITH[cd] '9'
```

Would get everything that does start with a number.

**edit** the comment prompted another idea:

If you could extract the first letter of the `name`, you could do:

```
NOT(name[0] IN %@), arrayOfLetters
```

(`name[0]` being the first character of `name`, and `arrayOfLetters` being an `NSArray` of the alphabetic characters)

Comment: I've not tried it, but it it might be possible to throw an array of letters at it, as the predicate processor seems to do pretty well with them other places. `predicate = "NOT(name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)", arrayOfLetters;` It would be prettier, anyway, and likely parsed faster. Assuming it works at all, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'MATCHES' where you can use any regex (e.g. ^[0-9]) to compare. But as far as I know that does not work when dealing with Core Data.

Another soluton would be to use the new (OS X 10.6, iOS 4.0) `predicateWithBlock:` and check the condition yourself with string methods.